# Enums Invisible to Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

In the code I'm working with, the authors like to do the following:

```
// someheader.h
typedef enum Something
{
    Something_None,
    #include "somelist.h"
    NumElements
} Something;
```

Within somelist.h it will have just a list of enum values:

```
item1,
item2,
item3,
```

After the first enum, there happens to be another enum:

```
typedef enum Another
{
    goodItem1,
    goodItem2,
} Another;
```

Now, when going through the code, eclipse can't resolve the items in somelist.h

```
#include "someheader.h"

SomeFunctionCall(item1); // <-- Can't resolve item1
SomeFunctionCall(goodItem1); // <-- No problem
SomeFunctionCall(Something_None); // <-- Same enum as item1 and yet no problem
```

And yet, if I make a project exactly like this, there's no problem finding item1 at all... So... I don't get it. Why doesn't it work in my massive project yet does in my tiny test?

Comment: Just because you can do something, doesn't mean you should...

Comment: I don't see any reason why include shouldn't be used in such manner.

Comment: Not my code, not my choice. And for super long lists (as is often the case here) it might be somewhat useful. Still, it is done and I don't get to choose :-).

Comment: My ide has no complaints, test with others ide's and report to eclipse devs.

Comment: Is it a "*super-long*" list in this case? How long is it? Perhaps Eclipse's indexer ran out of space. Pimp it! :-)

Comment: In this particular case, the list does happen to be 3 :-P.

Comment: Hmm... I tried an isolated case of this and it did indeed work just fine. Perhaps @alk is right, maybe the indexer is bombing from too much stuff. Can I give it more RAM?

Comment: How many elements do the enums have in the actual code?

Comment: This particular list is just like the example. So 5 total.